# Dynamic excel sum function

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, sum

I am trying to make a sum formula on a dynamic range. Much like in a pivot table.

Taking a look on the picture I want **L15** to be the sum of the range from L16 to the blank row. As the range is dynamic I am not sure how to write it on my code. So far what I have is this:

```
If out.Range("A15").Cells(i, 1) = "Aktier" Then
        out.Range("L15").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L15").Cells(i + 1, 1), Range("L15").Cells(i + 1, 1).End(xlDown))
End If
```

So my question is basically how do I write something like Sum(A1:End(xlDown))? :)

Hope you can help me out guys! :D

Thanks in advance!

[image: Data picture]

Comment: Try: `out.Range("L15").Cells(i, 1).Value = Application.Sum(out.Range(out.Cells(i + 1, 12), out.Cells(i + 1, 12).End(xlDown)))`

Comment: Hi there
Thanks for your quick reply however this only gives me the value "FALSE" after I've ran my sub.

Comment: Hello mate. This just gives me a 0 value :(

Comment: Please show more of your code. Are you looping over cells or are you only checking `A15` for "Aktier". Would be helpfull to know what `i` variable holds and what it does for you.

Comment: It is basically only this. After Aktier I have a line saying the same thing but using "Obligationer IG" and "UCITS alternative". 

i is just the row number for me so I am looping over different row numbers.

Comment: It does understand that the it needs to apply the if formula however the values it is trying to add up just results in 0. I have no errors whatsoever at least :-D

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend that every time that's possible, you get a structure more Data Base-like, so I would have a column repeating the concept and then you could use the Excel SUMIF function easily.

Probably that's not your case (that seems the output of an accounting program). Taking advantage of using VBA macros, you can use a loop to generate the column I mentioned before (you could do the sum as well using the concept, but I believe is cleaner generating a better data format). Please see the image below:[image: Excel Sample to Try Macro]

```
Sub Add_Concepts()

i = 1
Concept = Cells(i, 2)
i = 2
Do While (Cells(i, 2) <> "")
 Cells(i, 1) = Concept
 If Cells(i + 1, 2) = "" Then 'Change in concept
  Concept = Cells(i + 2, 2) 'New concept
  i = i + 2 'add 2 to skip the New concept line and the white space
 End If
  i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Now you can use the regular Excel functions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not so good at VBA yet so not quite sure I follow the code I'm afraid, however thanks a lot for contributing to my queston :D

Answer (score 0):

### Skipping Steps

**Snippet:**

```
If out.Range("A15").Cells(i, 1) = "Aktier" Then
    With out.Range("L15")
        .Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction _
          .Sum(.Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Offset(1).End(xlDown)))
    End With
End If
```

**Working example:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumToBlank()

    Dim out As Worksheet: Set out = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long: i = 1

    If out.Range("A15").Cells(i, 1) = "Aktier" Then
        With out.Range("L15")
            .Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction _
              .Sum(.Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Offset.End(xlDown)))
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Still cant seem to get it work. Isn't there just a simple function with sum(A1:End(xlDown))? Like when I count rows I can use use Range("F5", PF3.Range("F5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count. Isnt there something like this for sum?

Comment: Like, I am not sure why this wouldn't work:

out.Range("L15").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(out.Range("L15").Cells(i + 1, 1), Range("L15").Cells(i + 1, 1).End(xlDown)))

Comment: @Lelung: i've updated my answer. It was wrong previously.

Comment: This possibly would have been a short answer:          `out.Range("L15").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Range("L15").Cells(i + 1, 1), Range("L15").Cells(i + 1, 1).End(xlDown)))`. But the ranges are not being qualified, they refer to the `ActiveSheet` instead of `Sheets("out")`. If they're both the same it will work. But that's not how you write code.

Comment: The long code you posted in original post seems to work now. Many thanks :D I do have a problem however, I am sitting in a module with 8 different subs and not sure where to put my Option Explicit statement. When I try to put it on top on my sub it seems to add it as the last line in the previous sub? :( Not sure if I expressed myself correctrly though :)

Comment: There can only be one `Option Explicit` per `module` and it goes to the top. BTW is this happening on two different worksheets? I mean is `out` one worksheet and the other is the ActiveSheet?

Comment: The code only works when I add it in a separate module I am afraid. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The first subs in the sheet cannot run as I've added Option Explicit. It says "Compile error: Variable not defined".

Comment: I have quite a few worksheets in the excelsheet and "out" is actually the same name in the different worksheets however this calculation I only want for my active worksheet. The other worksheets are different calculations/tables.

Comment: Finally it doesnt seem to work when I change Aktier to Ucits alternative. It really is annoying me like crazy this hahah